# one-to-many relation using two columns in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my project I have a table `Translation` that can have translations for any model. To achieve this, the table has two fields: `Model` and `ModelId`. The `Model` property holds an integer indicating the type of the model and the `ModelId` has the id of this model.
So, for example: the `Product` table has modeltype id `1`. To get all translations for a product with id `317`, I search for translations with `Model=1 AND ModelId=317`.

Now I would like to create this relation in Entity Framework Core. All my models inherit from the class `BaseModel` that has a property `ModelType` holding the id of the model type. This field is not mapped, so it is not available in the database.

I have tried to create the relation using fluent api, but it doesn't allow me to specify more columns to filter on.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>()
    .HasMany<Translation>(bm => bm.Translations)
    // Extra filters
```

Is there any way to create this relation without having to manually create a join for every query that requires translations?

Comment: I am not aware of any EF features that allow you to do this out of the box. Note that for this to work, your database must inherently have forgone a FK constraint on the ID column; which makes it night impossible to query (or update) the correct data on the fly. This will become a two step process, as the table name (step one) will influence the ID lookup logic (step two). I would suggest writing either a custom `DbContext`, or a custom `Repository` that populates the necessary navigation property for you.

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>()` will make your `BaseModel` *entity* and EF will map it using [TPH inheritance strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance). In other words, to a **single** database table. I guess this is not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Since `modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>()` will use `TPH` inheritance approach, I assume you are not using EF code first approach for database creation and you are using it to map your models to an existing database. Then you can try something like this:

**Models:**

```
public class Translation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Model { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public BaseModel(int modelType)
    {
        ModelType = modelType;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ModelType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }// only for internal use
    public IEnumerable<Translation> ModelTypeTranslations
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Translations.Where(t => t.Model == this.ModelType);
        }
    }

}

public class SomeModel : BaseModel
{
    public SomeModel() : base(1) { }
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherModel : BaseModel
{
    public AnotherModel() : base(2) { }
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    ...

    public DbSet<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SomeModel> SomeModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnotherModel> AnotherModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>().HasKey(e => e.Id);

        var baseModelTypes = typeof(BaseModel).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(BaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t != typeof(BaseModel)).ToList();

        foreach (var type in baseModelTypes)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>().HasOne(type).WithMany(nameof(BaseModel.Translations)).HasForeignKey(nameof(Translation.ModelId));

            modelBuilder.Entity(type).Ignore(nameof(BaseModel.ModelType));
            modelBuilder.Entity(type).Ignore(nameof(BaseModel.ModelTypeTranslations));
            modelBuilder.Entity(type).HasKey(nameof(BaseModel.Id));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see you can use `ModelTypeTranslations` to get Translations only for current model type.

I should note this approach may have performance issues since it filters `Translations` by `ModelType` only in memory. Also I tried to avoid filtering in memory by using [`lazy loading`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) but I got [some exception](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11704) even if I just installed that package without invoking `optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`. I hope it will be fixed in the next releases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Use this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>()
.HasMany(bm => bm.Translations)
.WithForeignKey(x => new { x.Key1, x.Key2 });
```

Key1 and Key2 obviously need to be the keys to the relation and you may also need to define them as such (in the same order) for the Translation entity.

Comment: This doesn't work. The lambda function expects a return type of `IEnumerable<TRelatedEntity>`.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the `WithForeignKey` function exists.

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships