# Entity Framework Core: many-to-many relationship between generic object tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a Cat and Dog table and I want to create many-to-many relationships to an Image table. I don't want to create a join table for every table (DogImage, CatImage, BirdImage, etc) so I figured I would create a single EntityImage join table and then use a Type field to know what type of image it is. Here is my attempt at the model below, however this creates CatId, DogId, etc foreign keys in the EntityImage table, instead of using the EntityId I tried to define. Does anyone know how to handle this properly with the latest Entity Framework Core?
Thanks!

```
public class Cat
{
    [Key] public int CatId { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityFile> Files { get; } = new List<EntityFile>();
}

public class Dog
{
    [Key] public int DogId{ get; set; }
    public string DogName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityImage> Images { get; } = new List<EntityImage>();
}

public class Image
{
    [Key] public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImageName{ get; set; }
    public Byte[] Content { get; set; }
}

public class EntityImage
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int ImageType { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<EntityImage>().ToTable("EntityImage").HasKey(t => new { t.EntityId, t.ImageId });
}
```

Comment: Use an Animal table, from which Dog and Cat inherit (read : Dog and Cat have primary key = foreign key to animal), and create your join table between Animal and Image.

Comment: Then, to identify a certain kind of animal, I would go for Cat and Dog to have primary / foreign key animalId, and a column AnimalKind in the Animal table for your application to know which animal it is. This solution is not perfect (allows an animal to be a cat and a dog at the same time in the db), but unfortunately any solution has drawbacks in this situation.

Comment: Interesting thought, however I only used animals as an example to explain the problem. My real tables may or may not be related and it may or may not make sense to inherit from a common class.

Comment: But apparently, the do have some thing in common, they are all linked to image(s). Even if it's vague, isn't that enough to justify some base class "EntityWithImages" ?

Comment: for information about ways to represent some inheritance with EF : https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance

Comment: @Pac0 If you follow your link, you'll see that EFC currently supports only TPH (i.e. single table), which is not good for storing entities with the only common thing being images. If and when they add TPT, then may be. But for now I don't think this is viable option.

Comment: @Primico What are you trying to achieve is not possible. EF (Core) supports only real FK based relationships, while you are seeking for polymorphic (or more generally, logical) associations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059341/one-to-many-relation-using-two-columns-in-entity-framework-core is similar, and as you can see, there is no working answer.

Comment: Yes you'r rigth, I completely mixed EF and EFCore capabilities, sorry

Answer (score 0):

EF Core doesn't have some of the more sophisticated relationship handling (e.g. hierarchical) yet.

In your particular example, you could just use

```
public class Animal {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public byte[] Image {get; set;}
}

public class Cat : Animal {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

In EF 6, you could have Animal, Dog & Cat all go to different tables.  EF would set up the keys & navigation fields for you.  The type of object (Dog/Cat) would control which records in Animal you would see.  Note that this is a specialized case of one-to-one relationship (hierarchical).

You mentioned many to many, but I find it not very likely that two animals share the same image and if duplication of Name across species is an issue, move Name to the derived classes (Dog/Cat).

At some point EF Core will probably do this, I just haven't seen it yet (DataAnnotation/Fluent).